# post form to remote URL and extract URL from XML reponse

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AJAX submit form to remote URL and extract URL from XML reponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303065/ajax-submit-form-to-remote-url-and-extract-url-from-xml-reponse)

What is the best way to prosess this form are there any form handeling scripts which can help

I have a form which posts to remote url and returns a XML response containing some data and a URL. I need to extract the url and redirect to the URL in the XML response.

Here is my form

```
<form target="_blank" action='https://requesturl.co.uk/requestservice.asmx/Request_v4' method="POST"  >
<input type='hidden' value='' name='AffiliateID' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AffiliatePW' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqMode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqTotalTimeout' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqLenderTimeout' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqLoanAmount' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppTitle' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppFirstName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppLastName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppEmail' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppDOBYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHomePhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppWorkPhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppMobilePhone' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppPostCode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHouseNumber' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppStreet' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppTown' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppCounty' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpIncomeType' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpEmployerName' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpTimeAtEmployer' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNetMonthlyPay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpPayFrequency' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpDirectPayment' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNextPayYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayDay' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayMonth' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpFollowingPayYear' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='EmpNINumber' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankAccount' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankSortcode' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='BankDebitCard' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppAddressYears' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppAddressMonths' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='AppHomeStatus' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqConsent' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqIPAddress' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqAgent' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqMarketingOptIn' /><input type='hidden' value='' name='ReqDomain' />
<input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button">
```

The XML response is

```
<RequestResult><Result>Accepted</Result><FailureReasons/><AcceptedLender>LendingStream</AcceptedLender><RedirectURL>http://redirecttothisURL.com/testing.htm</RedirectURL><PPDReference>6524845</PPDReference></RequestResult>
```

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If you have anything to add, edit the original question.

Answer (score 0):

use xml DOM to read the xml. retrieve the data of node "RedirectURL" and redirect using header()